# Can't find the default Wallpapers

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04, directory, desktop-background, default

I changed my wallpaper from a diffrent folder and now I can't find the default ones that come with the system. Does anyone know where they are located in xubuntu? When I right click to change Desktop the folder is not visible I'm afraid of breaking something

Comment: Have a look in `/usr/share/wallpapers` or `/usr/share/backgrounds/`  ... Sorry I have multiple DEs installed & don't know the name of wallpaper to see where it's located (I have all Xubuntu & other flavor wallpapers installed though.. and they have varied with time).  ps:  by navigating to different directories you won't *break* anything, at worst you'll end up in a different directory as you likely are now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package [`xubuntu-wallpapers`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/xubuntu-wallpapers) contains these files

```
/usr/share/doc/xubuntu-wallpapers/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/xubuntu-wallpapers/copyright
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-artful.png
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-bionic.png
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-cosmic.png
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-development.png
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-disco.png
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-eoan.png
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-focal.png
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-hirsute.png
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-impish.png
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-jammy.png
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-wallpaper.png
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-xenial.png
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-yakkety.png
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-zesty.png
```

where you'll notice they're located in `/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops`

Note:  I'm a lover of wallpapers & thus have ~all *flavors* and main Ubuntu wallpapers installed; they aren't all in the same directories, but common places to look are in `/usr/share/wallpapers` and `/usr/share/backgrounds` but they do vary on *flavor* and DEsktop.

ps: *by navigating to different directories you won't break anything, at worst you'll end up in a different directory as you likely are now*

Note: *looking at the [*manifest*](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/jammy/daily-live/current/jammy-desktop-amd64.manifest) for the current *jammy* daily, there are more wallpapers than my answer here provides...   I didn't validate they're in the same location.*

Comment: A released *manifest* may make more sense to most people; but I use the dailies most often (in QA) so those URLs are *known* to me.. thus my using that URL.  Other packages included are `xubuntu-community-wallpapers` and `xubuntu-community-wallpapers-jammy` so anyone who wants to see what's included can just use https://packages.ubuntu/com to *peek* inside like my answer